# Delphi 7, how to copy Paintbox content to a Tbitmap?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, draw

im working on **delphi 7** and i want to how to copy/assign the content of a TpaintBox to a Tbitmap?

like this

```
 public
  { Public declarations }
   BitMap     : TBitmap;
 end;
```

i have a Tbitmap declared as public and i create it onFormCreate like this

```
      procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      begin
      BitMap     := TBitMap.Create;
      end;
```

Then i draw somthing on the bitmap like this

```
      procedure TForm1.DrawOnPainBox;
        begin
         If BitMap.Width  <> PaintBox1.Width  then BitMap.Width  := PaintBox1.Width;
         If BitMap.Height <> PaintBox1.Height then BitMap.Height := PaintBox1.Height;
         BitMap.Canvas.Rectangle(0,0,random(PaintBox1.Width ),random(PaintBox1.Height));
         PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0,0,BitMap);
        end;
```

with `PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0,0,BitMap);` we can display what is there in Bitmap to a paintbox but what is the  reverse way?

how to assign/copy content of a paintbox to a bitmap?

```
 `BitMap:=PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Bitmap;`
```

this compiles but if i do this and again call the `procedure TForm1.DrawOnPainBox;` i get `access Violation` and the debugger show the `bitmap` and `PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Bitmap` even though some lines are drawn on the paintBox

[image]

[image]

Comment: The `Bitmap` of the *brush*, is *not* the actual bitmap!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand  Ok, then how to get the actual bitmap?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To assign the contents of a `TPaintBox` (let's call it `PaintBox1`) to a `TBitmap` (`Bitmap`,  say), you can do

```
Bitmap.Width := PaintBox1.Width;
Bitmap.Height := PaintBox1.Height;
BitBlt(Bitmap.Canvas.Handle,
  0,
  0,
  Bitmap.Width,
  Bitmap.Height,
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle,
  0,
  0,
  SRCCOPY);
```

**Notice:** In newer versions of Delphi, you can use `Bitmap.SetSize` instead of `Bitmap.Width` and `Bitmap.Height`.

Comment: hey, it says `Undeclared identifier: 'SetSize'`

Comment: @PresleyDias: No, I don't think so. You must have done something wrong.

Comment: `procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Bitmap.SetSize(PaintBox1.Width, PaintBox1.Height);
BitBlt(Bitmap.Canvas.Handle,0,0,Bitmap.Width,Bitmap.Height,PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle,0,0,SRCCOPY);
end;`   for this im getting `Undeclared identifier: 'SetSize'`

Comment: @PresleyDias: Are you sure that you have declared a variable named `Bitmap` with type `TBitmap`?

Comment: @PresleyDias: OK, I see now that `SetSize` has not always been a member of `TBitmap` (it probably isn't in Delphi 7 -- I am using Delphi 2009). So, instead, simply do `Bitmap.Width := PaintBox1.Width; Bitmap.Height := PaintBox1.Height`

Comment: ok, but `Bitmap.Width := PaintBox1.Width; Bitmap.Height := PaintBox1.Height` this will copy the content of paintbox to bitmap?

Comment: @PresleyDias: No, that will merely set the size of the bitmap to the right size. The `BitBlt` does the copying.

Comment: yes, thanks that did the trick, it works ,can you please update the answer in terms of `delphi 7` so i can accept it

Answer (score 2):

TBitmap.setsize has been introduced in Delphi 2006, you may be using an older version. Just replace 
`Bitmap.SetSize (X, Y)`

by

```
Bitmap.Width := X
Bitmap.Height := Y
```

it's slower (but it matters only if you use it in a loop), but you will compile the code

if this happens too often, declare a new unit BitmapSize.pas:

```
unit BitmapSize;

interface

uses
    graphics;

Type
    TBitmapSize = class (TBitmap)
    public
        procedure Setsize (X, Y : integer);
    end;



implementation

procedure TBitmapsize.Setsize(X, Y: integer);
begin
    Width := X;    // may need some more tests here (X > 0, Y > 0, ...)
    Height := Y;
end;

end.
```

then replace in declaration and creation of your bitmap TBitmap with TBitmapSize.

```
..
Var
  B : TBitmapSize;
..
  B := TBitmapSize.Create;
```